# getting different location even if I am not moving

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocoding, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am using below code for getting `longitude` and `latitude` , but it gives me diifferent values even if I am **not** moving from my place

```
 locationmanager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    geocoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    locationmanager.delegate=self;
    locationmanager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [locationmanager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationmanager startUpdatingLocation];



    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"Failed to get Location." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
        CLLocation *currentlocation=newLocation;

    if (currentlocation!=nil)
    {

        longitude=currentlocation.coordinate.longitude;
        latitude=currentlocation.coordinate.latitude;

    }
         [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentlocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

          } ];

    }
```

please guide me, I want same location, if I am **not** moving from my place.

Comment: That's probably impossible.  The hardware is constantly refining (or altering) its calculated position as signal strength and clarity changes.  Unless you can freeze all atmospheric effects and all movement, your reported position is going to change even if you don't move.

Comment: Sorry what I meant by same lat long is same address. I want to fetch same address everytime I use THAT location. Can you please help?

Comment: Are you getting a different geo-coding answer for the same lat and long, or different answers for slightly different lat and long?

Comment: You're only supposed to ask for a single geocode lookup on the user's specific request, and then no more than once per minute. The code you posted will get your app rejected from the app store. You should both add a distance filter, and also add logic to ask at most once per minute, but even that doesn't satisfy Apple's guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Cellular network location gives an approximate area were the phone existing. It is based on the service providers tower.So current location will automatically changes a bit depending on network/gps location tracking/accuracy.

I recommend you to get location using distance filter, so until you are in that region your current address will remain same as location only updates for every X meters.

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;//Your own distance
```

i.e.,

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    // This is the most important property to set for the manager. It ultimately determines how the manager will
    // attempt to acquire location and thus, the amount of power that will be consumed.
    _locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
    // Once configured, the location manager must be "started".
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree. A distance filter will cut down on the "chatter" from the GPS.

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController.h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *location;
}
```

In ViewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     location = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     location.delegate = self;
     location.distanceFilter = 100;
     [location requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
     [location requestAlwaysAuthorization];
     [location startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *locati = [locations lastObject];
    float lat=locati.coordinate.latitude;
    float lon=locati.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"%f %f",lat,lon);

    [location stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

In your info.plist add :

[image]